# How to bind to an async image source

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I would like for instead of the image source to be bound to the `Image` property of my binding source, but to point to an async method which fetches the image remotely. I need to be able to pass in the two parameters.

**Image Fetch**

```
class ConnectImage
{
    public static async Task<BitmapImage> GetImageAsync(Uri uri, String sid)
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "OAuth " + sid); 

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);

        BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
        byte[] byteArray = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

        InMemoryRandomAccessStream ras = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(ras.GetOutputStreamAt(0));
        writer.WriteBytes(byteArray);
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.SetSource(ras);
        return image;
    }
}
```

**ListView**

```
<ListView
        x:Name="itemListView"
        Grid.Row="1"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"
        IsSwipeEnabled="False"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FeedItemTemplate}"/>
```

**FeedItemTemplate**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FeedItemTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Width="110" Height="110">
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties cannot be `async`, so you need an `async` initialization that will set the property at its completion.

In your VM:

```
public BitmapImage Image { get; private set; }

public async Task Load()
{
  Image = await ConnectImage.GetImageAsync(...);
  ... // other asynchronously-loaded properties
}
```

And then have your page `Loaded` event load your VM:

```
public async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  await vm.Load();
}
```

Your page will initially display with `Image` set to `null`, and when the image is loaded, it will show on the page.

Comment: Thanks, I also realized this is the only way.